# scala vscode Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name

Tags: java, scala, visual-studio-code

i am trying to install scala in vs code but it's not working (or running) and i have this error

this is my code

```
object assd extends App{
 print("dfdfdfdfdf")
}
```

and this is the error

```
[Running] scala "c:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\scala\tempCodeRunnerFile.scala"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$Loader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:314)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.RichClassLoader$.$anonfun$tryClass$extension$1(ScalaClassLoader.scala:47)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.$anonfun$opt$1(Exception.scala:245)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:227)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.opt(Exception.scala:245)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.RichClassLoader$.tryClass$extension(ScalaClassLoader.scala:47)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.tryToLoadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.tryToLoadClass$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:119)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.tryToLoadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:161)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.classExists(ScalaClassLoader.scala:189)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.guessHowToRun(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:43)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:62)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:25)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:45)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:108)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.99 seconds
```

and this is path window[path window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMa0m.png)

These are the extensions that I added
[scala](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADQBM.png)
[code runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P295q.png)

Comment: Have a look at [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-intro-to-scala-part-1-installation-set-up-and-hello-world-58a076a6818e#:~:text=%E2%80%9CHello%20World%E2%80%9D%20in%20VS%20Code,the%20file%20and%20then%20save.) It explains the way to configure scala with VSCode. Make sure you have everything in place and try configuring it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

if you use code runner,you can set scala change
`"scala": "cd $dir && scala $fileName",`